# Angular $resource Passing XML in a querystring

Tags: xml, json, angularjs

I have a service with two methods. One gets dummy data from a local json file, and the other gets real data from the server:

```
angular.module('accountHistoryApp')
.factory('HistoryService', ['$resource','$http', '$log', function ($resource, $http, $log) {

    return {
        getDummyAccountHistory: function() {
            return $resource('data/history1.json');
        },
        getAccountHistory: function(requestXML) {
            return $resource("http://foo.com/GetHistoryJSON",
                { requestXML: '@requestMXL'},
                { getAccountHistory:
                    {
                        method:'GET',
                        isArray:true ,
                        cache: false
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

When getDummyAccountHistory is called, everything works fine -- the history1.json file is local, and mirrors exactly the JSON returned by the server service call.

But when getAccountHistory is called, I can't get the querystring right. It  needs to be as follows:

```
http://foo.com/GetHistoryJSON?requestXML=<RequestXML><Id>J69258E</Id><USER_ID>55AE8</USER_ID><ACCOUNT_N>Y01000078</ACCOUNT_N></RequestXML>
```

All of the XML is passed in in the "requestXML" parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding your XML query string? You'll likely need to decode the string on the server as well...

Comment: @Sunil thanks but that's not what I'm asking. I want to know what the correct syntax is to create that request.

Comment: You didn't really say what was wrong, other than you can't get the query string right. What errors do you see w/the above code? What is the client sending in the query string, and what is the server seeing? But frankly, the first thing I would suspect is that browsers/servers might do funny things w/characters like `/` and perhaps `<` and `>` in urls :)